# Unable to use OpenTelemetry span with generators merged via aiostream.stream.merge

Tags: python, python-asyncio, open-telemetry

My opentelemetry spans are losing their parents when I create them within an async generator that I then merge with another async generator.

I believe the problem is that the span created within stream_fn is getting lost as the merged stream swaps between contexts on the event loop while awaiting.

Now, I know that I could manually restore the context after awaiting in this scenario, butin my real scenario restoring the context manually at every await would be very clunky and error prone.

how can I pass the context through properly when merging the streams?

Here is a minimal repro in the form of a self contained pytest

````
from collections import defaultdict
from aiostream import stream
from opentelemetry import trace
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import TracerProvider
from opentelemetry.trace import get_current_span


async def test_recurse_streaming_context():
    trace.set_tracer_provider(TracerProvider())

    async def stream_fn(title):
        with tracer.start_as_current_span(title):
            context = get_current_span().get_span_context()
            yield (title, format(context.span_id, "016x"))
            await asyncio.sleep(0)
            context2 = get_current_span().get_span_context()
            yield (title, format(context2.span_id, "016x"))

    acc = defaultdict(list)
    tracer = trace.get_tracer("test_tracer")
    with tracer.start_as_current_span("test span"):
        async for e in stream.merge(*[stream_fn(f"child_{i}") for i in range(2)]):
            acc[e[0]].append(e[1])

    assert acc["child_0"][0] == acc["child_0"][1]
    # AssertionError: assert 'caa5694e43a514db' == '57adf8fb9e10a596'```
````